# Filter Multiple Columns between multiple range

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a very big data contains nnumerical values mostly. I want to filter multiple columns that each is between different range. The problem is columns and range will be selected by user which means that filtered columns and ranges can be changed each time.

e.g `0<df[a]<5 & 0<df[b]<10`. It can be "a" and "b" and "c" also, totaly depend on input.

I want to see how many rows in a range such that for example; for each column; col.a is between "0" and "1", "1" and "2" etc. until 5 and same for col.b or any other until e.g "10"

Because of my code is very long , tried to explain the attached some part inside strings:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
excel_file: readed excel file dataframe
entered_parameters: (list) to be filtered columns typed by user
parameters: readed columns of excel_file
limits: (list) upper_limits inputted by user for each entered_parameters
ranges: range or incrementation list for each entered parameters
boolean_frame: Boolean dataframe returned for filtering each entered_parameters(columns) upto limits in each cycle
total_boolean_frame:appended boolean_frame(shows ranges up to limits for each parameter)
total_frame: concat of total_boolean_frame (shows all filtered boolean values by range for all param)

"""


total_frame=pd.DataFrame()
parameters=[i for i in excel_file.columns if type(i)==str]

totalrownumberlist=[]
for i,v in enumerate(limits):
    if i==0:
        totalrownumberlist.append(len(excel_file)*v)
    else:
        totalrownumberlist.append(totalrownumberlist[i-1]*v)
totalrownumber=totalrownumberlist[-1]
for i,param in enumerate(entered_parameters):

    total_boolean_frame=pd.DataFrame()
    appended_row_num=totalrownumberlist[i]
    if param in parameters:
        while appended_row_num<=totalrownumber:

            boolean_frame=pd.DataFrame()
            initial=0


            while initial<limits[i]:                          

                boolean_frame[param]=(excel_file[param]>=initial) & (excel_file[param]<=initial+ranges[i])

                boolean_frame["aralik-%s"%param]="%s-%s"%(initial,initial+ranges[i])


                initial=initial+ranges[i]

                total_boolean_frame=total_boolean_frame.append(boolean_frame,sort=False,ignore_index=True)

            appended_row_num=appended_row_num+totalrownumberlist[i]
        total_frame=pd.concat([total_frame,total_boolean_frame],axis=1)`
```

Edit: Output should be like this; count(range[0-1] col.a and range[0-1] col.b)=2 (avg. through axis=1 if all cells in the row is True which means avg of rows for excel_file[total_frame.all(axis=1)]. count(range[1-2] col.a and range[0-1] col.b)=3 with avg. again, count(range[2-3] col.a and range[0-1] col.b)=6 and avg. and goes on...
Thnks

Comment: Could you post a simple example of data and the expected output ?

Comment: Can groupby be useful